# javascript looping out specific key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

Hello I have an array in javascript with 3 objects in it each object has multiple sub objects and every sub object has a key and value obviously.

I am trying to loop out the subobject id of a certain key let's say for example 4 where the value is true.

What my array looks like:

[myarray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag4Hr.png)

I've tried this method: (result is the result of my ajax call it works)

```
for(var land in result.landen){
    $.each(land, function() {
        $.each(this, function(key, value) {
            console.log(key + value);
        });
    });
}
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in 8

Comment: Could you show a sample of the actual object instead of a pseudo representation of it.

Comment: Could you add a jsFiddle to help you out?

Comment: To break out of a nested loop, you simply have to do `return false;` if a certain condition is true.

Comment: I am working for the first time on a mac can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: Go to jsFiddle.net and you'll have different text boxes to add CSS, HTML and Javascript code. Add this sample, run it, save it and share the URL here

Comment: Your data looks strange. The properties `4` and `5` have no meaning. Are they properties of a country?

Comment: It's a bit tricky I am working on a wordpress site and I get my data from php and I send it to my jquery with an ajax call

Comment: May be you can show us the client side error mocking the AJAX response

Comment: the 4 and 5 are the id's of the type 4 is appartments 5 is warehouses and there is also 6 which is offices

Comment: There is no array here, only objects with properties so the `each` can't work ..

Comment: Is there an alternative for objects?

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, I think I understand this concept but what should I log to get my key and value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going 1 level too deep.

```
$.each(result.landen, function(key1, value1) {
    console.log(key1 + value1); 
    $.each(value1, function(key2, value2) {
        console.log(key2 + value2);        // will log "4 true"
    });
});
```

Your object structure is kind of weird in my opinion. Personnally, I'd rather have more explicit key/values.

```
{ landen :
    [
        {
            id : 8,
            type: 4
            apartements: [ //I don't know what they represent.
                {id : 8}
            ],
            warehouses: []
        }
    ]
}
```

Or something like that

Comment: @hacketo. No it's not. land is an object and you can iterate over an object's property. see doc http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: I get the same error, thanks for you help either way!

Comment: @phenxd the first each was not here when i commented... See your edits

Comment: I tried your edited response(assuming value3 must be value2?) and I get some weird error 0[object HTMLOptionElement] the errors go from 0 to 6 for 5 times

Comment: well the 8 13 15 17 19 are the id of different countries(landen means countries) in a certain country you have a building type(4 5 6)4 is the id of appartments, etc.

Comment: so you have 5 countries in the country with id 8 there are 2 buildings an (4)appartment and a (5)warehouse

Comment: See edit, IMO you should have arrays and 'id' keys so it's clear what the object represents

Comment: I think the problem here is the fact that I don't have arrays but objects like someone said in the comments on my question

Comment: Yeah. You could make it work as it is but to change it would be better practice

Comment: There must be a way to loop out the data I need, it looks relative simple :)

Comment: oops I had forgotten to change land to value1 in the forEach. see Edit

Comment: Okay I think it works, thanks a lot for your help! I go try some stuff out with the data. Thanks again mate